# How to catch specific redirect using playwright?

Tags: web-scraping, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-python

when Google Map is to some level confirmed about a place search it redirects to the specific Google place url otherwise it returns a map search result page.

Google Map search for "manarama" is

https://www.google.com/maps/search/manarama/@23.7505522,90.3616303,15z/data=!4m2!2m1!6e6

which redirects to a Google Place URL

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Manarama,+29+Rd+No.+14A,+Dhaka+1209/@23.7505522,90.3616303,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3755bf4dfc183459:0xb9127b8c3072c249!8m2!3d23.750523!4d90.3703851

Google Map search result page looks like the following link below when it is not confirmed about the specific place

https://www.google.com/maps/search/Mana/@24.211316,89.340686,8z/data=!3m1!4b1

```py
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto("https://www.google.com/maps/search/manarama/@23.7505522,90.3616303,15z/data=!4m2!2m1!6e6", wait_until="networkidle")
        print(page.url) 
        await page.close()
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Sometimes it returns the redirected URL, but most of the time, it doesn't. How to know the URL got redirected to a place URL for sure? the following StackOverflow post has similarities but couldn't make it work for my case

[How to catch the redirect with a webapp using playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72754334/how-to-catch-the-redirect-with-a-webapp-using-playwright)

Comment: What problem did you face when adapting the linked answer to your case?

Comment: what would be the url_or_predicate in my case for page.expect_response(url_or_predicate, **kwargs) and if doesn't redirect then what will happen? because it will not always redirect as you can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [expect_navigation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-navigation).

In the comments you mentioned about what url to match for with the function. Almost all such playwright functions accept [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) patterns. So when in doubt, just use regex. See the code below:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, TimeoutError
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"http.*://.+?/place.+")


async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        page = await browser.new_page()
        try:
            async with page.expect_navigation(url=pattern, timeout=7000) as resp:
                await page.goto(
                    "https://www.google.com/maps/search/manarama/@23.7505522,90.3616303,15z/data=!4m2!2m1!6e6",
                    wait_until='networkidle')
        except TimeoutError:
            print('place not found')
        else:
            print('navigated to place')

        print(page.url)
        await page.close()
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

In order to check whether the page navigated or not, just wrap the function inside a `try..except` block and pass a suitable `timeout` argument (in ms) to `expect_navigation`. Then if a `Timeout` error was raised, you know that there wasn't any url change which matched our pattern.

Comment: Thanks, @Charchit . It worked. Does it mean Google does the redirection in minimum 5 seconds? I tried 5000 at least.

Comment: it's more about your internet speed I guess, the only way to find such things are through trial and error. Just to make sure, `expect_navigation` expects the url to change to the one matching provided pattern,  so the timeout should be large enough to ensure that happens.